# DropboxSDK: Unable to upload folders ( ) for IOS SDK

Tags: ios5, ios-simulator, dropbox

I have problem with the file upload with DropBox SDK for IOS. When i try ti upload a file from my app's document folder .

I have followed this tutorial  :[tutorial](http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2011/1/20/how-to-synchronize-your-app-data-using-dropbox-api.html)

Getting error as

`[WARNING] DropboxSDK: Unable to upload folders (/Users/*******/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/DAE13E8C-9833-463C-A073-D114FB0FFD1A/Documents/contact)`

My code section is as below.

`[[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];`

Comment: I found the issue and fixed it . We need to give the local path of the file as whole . I have given only up to the folder. File name was not included .

Answer (score 4):

Your only problem is that "fromPath" expects not just the path but the path with the file name appended to it:

```
    NSString *sourcePath = [localPath stringByAppendingPathComponent: sourceFile];
    if ([app.globalObject fileExists: sourcePath]) {
        NSString *destDir = @"/";
        [[self restClient] uploadFile: sourceFile
                               toPath: destDir
                        withParentRev: nil
                             fromPath: sourcePath];
    }
```